# Unable to convert Timestamp to Datetime within array_push

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write data to an array from a MYSQL database.
One of the data values requires me to convert unix timestamp into datetime.
However, my output prints values in the form "0.1,0.2,..,1.1,1.2, etc..."
I am using the below code which works, but not when I try to add the code within the array.

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong?

```
$dataPoints = array();
foreach($ses_sql5 as $row){
        $dtms = date_create();
        date_timestamp_set($dtms ,$row['timestamp']);
        array_push($dataPoints, array("x"=> print(date_format($dtms, 'd-M-Y  H:i:s')), "y"=> $row['mark']));
    }
```

Comment: remove `print` keyword inside array_push

Comment: I have tried that as well with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, There is function to convert timestamp to date in the MySQL (FROM_UNIXTIME). If you want will do it in PHP you can use function date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row['timestamp']).

Comment: I have tried this approach and yes it will convert the date it does not work within the array_push function.